# K-Clustering of a Graph maximizing intra-cluster weights?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, approximation-algorithms, clustering, partition-problem

I would like to know if the following problem has already been studied, and if so how is it called. In particular I'm interested in approximability results.

**Input:** A complete graph G with non-negative integer weights on edges and an integer $K\ge 2$.

**Output:** A $K$-partition $P=\{P_1, ..., P_K\}$ of $V(G)$

**Measure (to maximize):** The sum of the weights for the edges with both endpoints in the same set of $P$, i.e.:
$$
M(P)=\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{u,v\in P_i} w\left( u,v \right)
$$
where $w$ is the edge-weight function.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this is [minimum k-cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_k-cut) on a complete graph? I think that maximizing the weight of intra-cluster edges should be the same as minimizing the weight of inter-cluster edges.

Comment: @mhum but that doesn't say much about approximability (it does show that the problem is NP-hard)

Comment: @mhum It is the same problem as minimum K-cut with respect to the optimal solution. This shows that the problem is NP-Hard but unfortunately an approximation algorithm for minimum K-cut isn't guaranteed to achieve the same approximation ratio on this problem.

Consider for example Min Vertex-Cover and Max Independent-Set. An optimal solution for one gives an optimal solution for the other but VC is approximable within a constant while IS is not.

Comment: It is also a version of the k-cluster editing or the k-correlation clustering. You may find several results in scholar google with the names as key words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is called MIN-SUM clustering and is NP-hard. There's a [paper by Bartal, Charikar and Raz](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~moses/papers/minsum.ps%E2%80%8E) from 2001 that has an approximation scheme for it: the paper also includes references to the NP-hardness result and other related results.